# How to build an app from javascript source files in GitHub app-catalog repository?

Tags: rally

How do I take the JS and CSS source for an app like the Iteration Tracking Board (https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/iterationtrackingboard) or Release Burndown (https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown) and turn that into HTML source that can be used as a Custom HTML app in a page in Rally?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

[rally-app-builder](https://github.com/RallyApps/rally-app-builder)

After source files are copied to a local directory (you may either fork [the app-catalog repo](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog), or download zip from the same location):

1. in terminal, cd to the app
2. call this command: `rally-app-builder build`.
   As a result a deploy folder is created with App.html and App-uncompressed.html inside, and App-debug.html is created in the root folder of the app.
3. Copy/paste App.html or App-uncompressed.html file from deploy folder to the HTML section of the custom page in Rally.